# WinHttp: can it be used in parallel?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I saw the following from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> WinHTTP is not reentrant except during asynchronous completion
> callback. That is, while a thread has a call pending to one of the
> WinHTTP functions such as WinHttpSendRequest, WinHttpReceiveResponse,
> WinHttpQueryDataAvailable, WinHttpSendData, or WinHttpWriteData, it
> must never call WinHTTP a second time until the first call has
> completed.
>
> One scenario under which a second call could occur is as
> follows: If an application queues an Asynchronous Procedure Call (APC)
> to the thread that calls into WinHTTP, and if WinHTTP performs an
> alertable wait internally, the APC can run. If the APC routine happens
> also to call WinHTTP, it reenters the WinHTTP API, and the internal
> state of WinHTTP can be corrupted.

Does this mean, while a thread is calling WinHTTP, "the thread itself" can no longer call into WinHTTP?

Or does it mean, while a thread is calling WinHTTP, not any other WinHTTP can be called in you whole program (even if they are in other threads.) ?

And could anyone explain the example provided my MSDN? If it is in sync mode, most WinHTTP functions are blocking? How could the APC run?

Comment: I wrote codes and found that even if it is working in multi threaded case. It seems fine, but for thread related issues it is hard to draw any conclusions out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean, while a thread is calling WinHTTP, "the thread itself" can no longer call into WinHTTP?

Yes. Different threads are allowed to make concurrent calls to WinHTTP.

Comment: So, to this similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669042/winhttp-multithreading-reentrant-issue, the answer is also Yes?

Comment: That's the same question. The answer is just the same.